# Can NHibernate load data from 2nd level cache after session is closed?

Tags: caching, nhibernate

I am trying stuff I can make with NHibernate for my app. I am using quite a lot of "dictionaries" to store all possible values for certain object properties. I've tried playing with 2nd level cache to store those dictionaries data in there. Now I wonder if there is a way to load needed data from cache after the session is closed. Let's say that is my code:

```
public class Class1 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Dic1 Dic { get; set; }
}

public class Dic1 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and here are the mappings:

```
<class name="Class1" table="class1">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <!-- I want to try not to use fetch="join" here -->
    <many-to-one
        name="Dic"
        class="Dic1"
        column="dic1_id"
    />
</class>

<class name="Dic1" table="dic1">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="name" />
</class>
```

If I get value of Class1.Dic object before I close the session, NHibernate does not send query to the database, because value was cached by some earlier query.

But let's say, I've closed the session. In debug session, Class1.Dic is an object of Dic1Proxy type and I get an exception when I try to access it/it's properties. Is there a way to load that data after session is closed? 2nd level cache is connected to session factory, so maybe there is a way to actually turn that Proxy into the right object? Or actually force to always load those values without changing `fetch` method to `join`.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. My understanding is that the second level cache is maintained at session factory level so that it can be shared among different sessions. Each session has an identity map that acts as its 'first level cache'. Where configured, I think the second level cache is used by the session as an option for retrieving data. I would be surprised if you could access the second level cache directly.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to force eager fetching, but not JOIN based, but using additional SELECTs? very quickly all values will be cached, so I really want to skip JOINing that data. Of course other way, would be to keep session alive on a per-window or per-control basis (yes, I am writing Windows app).

Comment: Yes, there is a way, with drawbacks. I have included it in my [answer](/a/50509375/1178314) through an edit, see its second paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NHibernateUtil.Initialize(class1.Dic);` before closing the session. It will do nothing if the object is not actually a proxy or if it is already loaded, otherwise it will load it (from the second level cache if cached).

You can also force eager fetching while keeping the default `select` fetch mode: set `lazy` as `false` on the `many-to-one` mapping of the `Dic` property. Loading a `Class1` will then trigger immediately a load of the `Dic` property. It should fetch it from second level cache if it is in it. Beware that this will cause n+1 loads issues if you query a list of `Class1` and if their `Dic` property is not cached, even if you have enabled [batching of lazy loads](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch).

Otherwise if you do not want to do any kind of manipulation on your `Dic` property before closing the session, you need to change the proxy implementation for it to first check the second level cache before failing if the session is already closed. But this will require too much work to be worth it, in my opinion. (Moreover, what if the entity is missing in the cache anyway? Is it acceptable for your application to fail in such case?)

NHibernate allows you to supply your own factory of proxy factory (`IProxyFactoryFactory`), by using the `proxyfactory.factory_class` [optional setting](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional), provided you use the default bytecode provider.

Then you would need to implement your own `IProxyFactoryFactory`, which would likely mostly be a copy of [`StaticProxyFactoryFactory`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Bytecode/StaticProxyFactoryFactory.cs) with `BuildProxyFactory` yielding a custom proxy factory.

The custom proxy factory would itself likely be mostly a copy of [`StaticProxyFactory`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Proxy/StaticProxyFactory.cs), with `GetProxy` using a custom `ILazyInitializer` [at this line](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Proxy/StaticProxyFactory.cs#L24).

The custom lazy initializer would in turn be likely a copy of [`LiteLazyInitializer`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Proxy/LiteLazyInitializer.cs), but with an override of `Initialize`. Its implementation is [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Proxy/AbstractLazyInitializer.cs#L107).

That is for the easy part, and till there, that is not as bad as it sounds, that does not involve copying so many lines of code.

Now for the override of `Initialize`, it would need to check the `Session` property and acts accordingly, calling its [base implementation](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Proxy/AbstractLazyInitializer.cs#L107) if the session is usable, or trying to directly load from the second level cache otherwise.

Here you would have more code to duplicate, mainly [LoadFromSecondLevelCache](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Event/Default/DefaultLoadEventListener.cs#L413) and [AssembleCacheEntry](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Event/Default/DefaultLoadEventListener.cs#L456).

You will also need the persister, which is easy to get if you have the session factory: `sessionFactory.GetEntityPersister(EntityName)`. (`ILazyInitializer` has an `EntityName` property.)

As you can see by checking their code, these functions use at many points the session:

- `CacheMode`: checked for ensuring the cache is enabled for the session, you surely should skip that check for your use case.
- `GenerateCacheKey`: easy to inline out of the session, see [its code](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Impl/AbstractSessionImpl.cs#L103).
- `Timestamp`: using `sessionFactory.Settings.CacheProvider.NextTimestamp()` instead should do it.
- `Instantiate`: use `subclassPersister.Instantiate(id)` instead. (Unless you have an interceptor to which it should be delegated.)

The other calls are more troublesome.
You will have to give-up on safe-keeping from circular references as this uses the session persistence context.
Then there is the `Assemble` and `DeepCopy` logic which use the session. Many cases just call its `Factory` property, so depending on the property types of your entities, a dummy session just actually supplying the factory may do.
Skip the readonly stuff if possible, otherwise you will have still more work to do.
Skip most of the `persistenceContext` stuff: that is the session first level cache. Still there is the `InitializeNonLazyCollections` call which will be lacking if your entities have some.
About `AfterInitialize`, this call is currently needed for handling entities having lazy properties (not being an entity or a collection). So you may be able to skip it.
And finally, the `PostLoadEvent` is there for entities implementing `ILifecycle`: again, you may be able to skip it, provided you do not use `ILifecycle`.

If you have also some cached collections to retrieve from the second level cache without a session, you would need to do a similar work with the collection type factory, configurable with the `collectiontype.factory_class`, providing your own `ICollectionTypeFactory` yielding collection types overriding [`Initialize`](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Collection/AbstractPersistentCollection.cs#L460), likewise duplicating [the loading from second level cache](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.2/src/NHibernate/Event/Default/DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.cs#L64).

Good luck if you try this.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer, which is the first one that tells something more, than what I already wrote :) I am really new to NHibernate, so going so deep into it is a bit too much for me at this moment. I am still reading docs (language barrier also does not help), having "try and fail sessions" most of the time ... but I am slowly getting the hang of it. I think, that I will keep Session alive for as long, as app window is alive, or at least as long as I don't have to make a full DataGridView refresh ... actually, is it resource consuming (memory) to keep Session alive?

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. I don't know how I missed the `lazy` setting in `many-to-one`. I thought I can only choose to use selects or joins as per `fetch` setting.

Comment: `lazy` is not documented on NHibernate side and is discoverable (for hbm mappings) only through the mapping schema file (xsd). But it is documented on Hibernate side, in their [old documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) (they seem to have somewhat obsoleted hbm mappings). `lazy` is indeed there to allow using the `fetch` mode `select` eagerly (among some other edge cases). About the session, answering is a bit off-topic, but keep in mind the longer it stays opened, the more you will have to deal with staled data.